# how invert the order of factors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, geom-bar, gplots

I am trying to reverse the order of the fill factor on the graph, i.e. The 0.5-1 class, must be at the top of the bar.. and then in descending order

```
gruppo <- c("TM", "TM","TM","TM", "PM", "PM","PM","PM")
valor <-c(1,4,237,3433,1,3,240,3700)
class <- c(">1", "0.5-1", "0.1-0.5", "<0.1")
df <- data.frame(Trait=gruppo, n_windows=valor, var_exp =class)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Trait, y=n_windows, fill=var_exp)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

I tried the reorder function, but don't work

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Trait, y=n_windows), fill=var_exp)) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

Comment: You can reverse the order by doing: `scale_fill_discrete(limits=rev)`

Comment: Mael this command change the colors , but not the order

Comment: @Rfanatic the y-axis is replaced by the information of var_exp

Comment: Try this  ggplot(df, aes(x= Trait, y=n_windows, fill=var_exp)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))